# How to resolve Laravel Logger Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 and a trying to load some info to the laravel.log file using the Log class as so

```
Log::info("Password reset request", array("User ID" => $id, 
                                          "Email"=>$email, 
                                          "Reset ID"=>$reset_id, 
                                          "Date"=>$date, 
                                          "Unix time"=>$time));
```

But nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: Did you try `php artisan tail`? If there was no error on running your web. then the log info should be shown in that command. try doing the command and visiting the page.

Comment: does laravel (apache/php) have permission to write to the file?

Comment: @CrayonViolent I believe laravel on dev will throw an error if it can't write to app/storage.

Comment: @majimboo well OP hasn't exactly provided any details about whether or not it's in dev mode or where/how he's calling this etc.. so I mean.. vague question gets vague suggestions/answers

Comment: Yes it's on dev, but no errors get thrown out and @majimboo php artisan tail threw out this error InvalidArgumentException Command "tail" is not defined

Comment: @DanielBarde first try php artisan list, is there anything that says tail or logs?

Comment: @majimboo no there's nothing like that in the list

Comment: @DanielBarde I guess the tail commands is setup with SSH http://laravel.com/docs/ssh

Answer (score 1):

You can use log viewer for this problem.

> 1. Install Package

```
composer require arcanedev/log-viewer
```

> 2. Need to configure package provider in config/app.php file and add following service

```
provider.
   'providers' => [
....
....
Arcanedev\LogViewer\LogViewerServiceProvider::class,
],
```

> 3.Publish the Config Package

```
php artisan log-viewer:publish
  php artisan log-viewer:publish  --force     
  php artisan log-viewer:publish  --tag=config
  php artisan log-viewer:publish  --tag=lang
```

> 4. Using environment (.env) file we can config base and required a key for our application. In this now we can add LOG_CHANNEL key for generating log file daily basic.

```
 LOG_CHANNEL=daily
```

> 5. That’s it just demonstrates the application using the following URL

```
http://your_application_path/log-viewer
```